# Using python to access JAVA API?

Tags: python

I have written a python scripts which get data from various sources(Quandl, webscraping etc) at the moment. I want to switch to a more stable information feed, order placement system. The broker provides an API:

https://www.sharekhan.com/active-trader/oalert/new-to-oalert

After looking through the docs and the scant information available it seems I can only use it with `java`. I am new-ish to python and have never tried java. Can someone point me in the direction of where to begin learning more about how to use the API in my python program/script?

From the FAQ

> TradeTiger API has a Transmission Control Protocol (TCP)-based architecture. So, it can work in any programming language that can communicate using the TCP protocol. Some programming languages that are compatible with the API are C#.net, VB.Net, Java, Python, C++ and VB.

Thanks

Comment: Unless your Python code runs under something like Jython, you can't use Java APIs from Python. Either you'll need a proper Python library that implements the API (which your quote from the FAQ suggests they supply), or there is an HTTP-based API that can be accessed via any language that supports HTTP requests.

Comment: @chepner While an HTTP-based API would be ideal, python can also work at the lower level of any generic TCP-based API.

Comment: The *architecture* may use TCP, but that doesn't mean it's a detail exposed at the API level. (Granted, it doesn't make a lot of sense to be listing languages that can support TCP communication.)

Comment: @chepner A quick glance at the documentation at https://www.sharekhan.com/Upload/General/TradeTigerAPIForClient.pdf shows that the API seems to be pure TCP with no sugary HTTP on top of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According the the quote you gave from the documentation, the API uses TCP. You can access this with any networking library in any language, including Python.

To start, you will need to learn the basics of TCP. A google search will lead you to the technical documentation. An RFC gives the official specification. Then you will need a Python library to open a network connection and send binary data. Finally, you will need to read [the documentation for the API](https://www.sharekhan.com/Upload/General/TradeTigerAPIForClient.pdf).

Comment: Thanks, can you point me to some resource where I can start reading/learning how to go about it?

Comment: @Sid You should start by learning the basics of TCP. A google search should point you to the technical documentation. Then read the API docuentation at https://www.sharekhan.com/Upload/General/TradeTigerAPIForClient.pdf and find a TCP library for python to implement the requests.